# Find all the elements that are fixed by $Frob_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Consider the finite field $\mathbb F_9 = \mathbb F_3[x]/ \langle x^2 + 1\rangle$, and recall the Frobenius isomorphism $Frob_3 : \mathbb F_3 → \mathbb F_3$, given by $Frob_3(x) = x^3$ Find all the elements of $\mathbb F_9$ that are fixed by $Frob_3$, and use this to see which
elements are fixed by $(Frob_3)^2 = Frob_3 ◦ Frob_3$.

What does it mean by find elements that are fixed by $Frob_3$? Can't find it anywhere. Please help.

Comment: the fixed points, the elements $a$ such that $g(a) = a$ are the fixed points of $g$

Comment: and the ring morphisms from $k[x]$ to itself are of the form $\phi(\sum_k a_k x^k) = \sum_k a_k \phi(x)^k$ (whenever $k = \mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{F}_p$ i.e. a field whose only one automorphism  is the identity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element of $\mathbb{F}_9 = \mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^2 + 1)$ is of the form $(x^2 + 1) + f(x)$, where $f(x) \in \mathbb{F}_3[x]$.

Let $\sigma : \mathbb{F}_9 \to \mathbb{F}_9$ be the Frobenius automorphism $\alpha \mapsto \alpha^3$. To say that an element $\alpha = (x^2 + 1) + f(x) \in \mathbb{F}_9$ is fixed by $\sigma$ means that $(x^2 + 1) + (f(x))^3 = (x^2 + 1) + f(x)$. For example, $(x^2 + 1) + 1$ is fixed by $\sigma$ because $1^3 = 1$.

Comment: I don't understand why they consider $x \to x^3$ if it is the identity.

Comment: My mistake, I have edited my post.

Comment: I just understood that the Frobenius endomorphism is $\sigma: R \to R, a \to a^p$ where $p$ is prime and is the characteristic of the ring $R$ (i.e. for every $a \in R$ : $\underbrace{a+\ldots+a}_p = 0$)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism . that was really stupid to write it $\sigma : x \to x^3$ for denoting $x \in \mathbb{F}_3[x] / (x^2+1)$...

Comment: and is this endomorphism also of the form $\sum_k a_k x^k \to \sum_k a_k \sigma(x)^k$ as the endomorphisms of $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ ?

Comment: @EthanAlwaise still not sure what being fixed by $Frob_3◦Frob_3$ means

Comment: For $(x^2 + 1) + f(x)$ to be fixed by the frobenius automorphism means $(x^2 + 1) + f(x) = (x^2 + 1) + (f(x))^3$, i.e. $x^2 + 1$ divides $f(x) - (f(x))^3$.